# Assign value based on one of multiple booleans

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to simplify the if statements of my code.
At the moment I have those 3 ugly if statements and I am looking for a way to assign the name of the `vm.model` property based on which one is currently true to `vm.model.status`.

Say `vm.model.received === true` I'd like to write something like

```
vm.model.status = //vm.model[name] << if vm.model.received/issued/cancelled true
```

Is it possible writing a better looking code in this case rather than repeating myself 3 times?

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.model = {
    received: true,
    issued: false,
    cancelled: false,
    anotherProp: 'abc',
    anotherProp2: 'def'
  }
  
  if(vm.model.received) {
     vm.model.status = 'received';
  } else if(vm.model.issued) {
     vm.model.status = 'issued';
  } else if(vm.model.cancelled) {
     vm.model.status = 'cancelled';
  }
  
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <form>
         <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.model.status" value="received">Received
         <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.model.status" value="issued">Issued
         <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.model.status" value="cancelled">Cancelled
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: If it's only those 3 conditions, it's better to keep it as it is. It's much more readable IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the keys/values into an array and find the value. You may need a default value as well.

```
vm.model.status = ['received', 'issued', 'cancelled'].find(k => vm.model[k]);
```